# Is content inserted using ngTemplateOutlet part of light or shadow DOM

Tags: angular

I can use [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html) directive to insert content. Is the inserted content part of light or shadow DOM? I'm wondering whether the styles written as part of components `styles` metadata property applied to this content?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the light DOM.

You can see it in the Dev Tools.